# Why must everything be a question?

Tags: feature-request

It seems like SO is dedicated to questions, but one thing that would be useful would be for people to share something they learned.  E.g. Recently I had an issue where I discovered IIS 7 is locked down so that even URL encoded strings which in turn contain an Ampersand are blocked from access.  To fix it required a Registry entry change, something I discovered only was referenced in two obscure places on the internet.  While I could have asked the SO community and waited for a bounty, one other option other than answering my own question would be to post the problem and solution.  I think there are community questions and wikis, but it may be useful to have a third element called something like Lessons Learned or something.

Comment: because SOFU isn't a personal tech blog?

Comment: See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/24608/what-is-the-etiquette-for-posting-an-article
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18864/can-i-post-how-to-articles-here
etc.

Comment: I don't know who originally coined SOFU, but I love it.

Comment: It's really MSOFU, but the M is silent and mostly ignored by the community.

Comment: STFU would be better but its close enough.

Comment: You can always ask (and answer) the question yourself. : ) I think the closest you can get outside of that is to daily scout the relevant tags for similar questions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I think the usual (and if I remember correctly, officially encouraged) way is in fact asking the question, and answering it by oneself.

As earlz points out, this is not a very widespread practice. That, however, is no reason not to put valuable content onto SO. I would say if your "monologue" question gets closed because people don't like your answering your own question, take the case here on Meta. If it's a good, valid question, you will most likely get good feedback here, the question reopened, and a meta link preventing future closures.

Comment: Yep - StackOverflow Jeopardy!

Comment: doo DOO doo *doo* doo DOO doo...

Comment: The thing is that this isn't done nearly often enough to be considered "appropriate" by most users (and thus, subject to closing and whatnot)

Comment: @earlz then the case would have to be taken to the court (i.e. here.) and if necessary, reopened with a link to the official meta verdict. I came across an excellent example just a few minutes ago: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2165022/how-can-i-troubleshoot-my-perl-cgi-script funnily enough, I've been thinking about opening a similar jeopardy question about PHP troubleshooting, seeing as many newbies don't know even the very basic steps of debugging. This is a practice that should be encouraged IMO.

Comment: @earlz: I have (successfully!) encouraged two users to do it in the last week. They received no backlash that I noticed. Can you point to example of people pushing against this practice?

Comment: @dmckee: I would be wary of accepting your own answer if there really is another good correct answer (example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2000861/retrieve-module-object-from-stack-frame/2011168#2011168), and I have seen backlash when the OP essentially repeats another answer and then accepts it (but, of course, don't have the URL handy).

Comment: @Gnome Personally *I* always make my self answer CW (note: not the question). And I can see here answerers would feel cheated if the OP accepts his own answer fully equivalent to one offered by another person. But that's not a problem for Jeopardy questions where I write the question and answer in emacs, paste in the question and then immediately paste in the answer; which is the situation *this* poster is asking about.

Comment: @dmckee: I see your point for questions you *plan* to self-answer, but I disagree in the example I gave.  And it's not about rep (which I almost completely don't care about on SO being over 10k, but is relevant to most), because CW should imply a stronger sense of "community ownership" and encourage editing by others much more than usual. -- Basically, I agree with you, but wanted to make a distinction for others coming upon this question later.

Comment: In fact, here's another example where the answer isn't CW, but could benefit from being CW because it really is a blog post on SO and others could improve/correct/etc. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2474018/when-does-invoking-a-member-function-on-a-null-instance-result-in-undefined-behav

Answer (score 3):

It is perfectly fine to document the issue you solved by asking a question and answering your own question. Just keep the time between the question and answer short (e.g. prepare it in advance). You can also leave a comment to your question explaining why you answered your own question and perhaps add a reference to one of the articles below.

See the answers to these questions:

[Is it poor etiquette to answer your own question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17463/is-it-poor-etiquette-to-answer-your-own-question)

[Should I answer my own question, or not?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12513/stackoverflow-should-i-answer-my-own-question-or-not)

[Why could it be considered gaming the system if you answer your own question?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15007/why-could-it-be-considered-gaming-the-system-if-you-answer-your-own-question)

[Etiquette for answering your own question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question)

[Consistently Answering your Own Questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/23712/consistently-answering-your-own-questions)