# MicroBlogging/Reviews/Experience articles

Tags: feature-request

Although I am aware of [the way "how-to" questions should be addressed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/18864/2684), I still find it a little bit incomplete for some other things.

On Apple.SE (and Apple users in general) often find themselves struggling to find information whether a certain device will work under OSX and if it does, to what extent. A common example are mice and keyboards with Windows-Only drivers/software. Of course the Keyboard will work, but how about those nice Leds/Buttons/Macros/Etc. I imagine Linux Users (and other less common OSs) finding themselves in the same situation.

Googling for these types of things, returns an array of mixed results. More often than not, it's just a simple reference to the Windows page of the product that happens to contain OS X or MAC somewhere but doesn't really talks about *that*.¹

Worst case scenario, you get a ExpertSexChange link.

Usually asking: "Does anyone know how -XYZ- works under -OS-?" and then waiting a few days and posting your own experiences may work, but not always. It happened to me. This is a common scenario on "rare" OSses like OS X (as compared to Windows). Some things, you always wonder how are they going to work (if they work at all).

**So**, how about SE providing a small space, to certain users (rep?) to "microblog" about something. It should be integrated as it should benefit from Tags/comments/etc.

E.g.: A user would want to share his experience with a Razer Naga Mice under OS X, showing how the system works, caveats, things that fail, etc. This is not a Wordpress blog replacement. And I know this could be posted on a blog and then redirected there, but then the whole thing is outside S.E. network, and I believe the idea is to keep users IN here whenever possible, gaining the benefit of reputation and "knowing" who's writing.

I haven't put too much thought into it and maybe it doesn't make any sense, maybe just question/answer is enough, but I find using a question/self-answer a little bit awkward for some things. But when I think about it, users with XX rep having a small "board" of articles and experiences doesn't sound like a bad Idea anyway.

What do you think?

¹ <sub>In case you're wondering, yes, this happened to me, and that's why I came up with the idea</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, as long as the site allows product compatibility questions, I would suggest posting it as if it were a question, then answering it yourself.  In this way you provide the information to the site, it fits the site's style and goals, and future searchers will enjoy the benefit of your knowledge.